# SQL Server: selecting specific values from arbitrary nodes in XML data output - Answered

Tags: sql-server, string, select, sqlxml

I have an XML Output from machine testing that looks like this that I need to extract specific data from a node that I can't really specify for each test case:

```
<TestResult>
  <MethodResult
     X
     X
     X
    <StepResult name = "FlowError" status = "ProductFailure"> 
      <ActualValue>
        <Number value = "3" />
      </ActualValue>
      <Limit constraint Type = "In Range" name = "FlowError">
        <Low>
          <Number value = "5" />
        </Low>
        <High>
          <Number value = "6" />
        </High>
      </Limit>
      <Error source="X" code="Y" mesg="Failed for X; Value was 3, expected [5 to 6]/> 
    </StepResult>
  </MethodResult>
</TestResults>
```

As you know can guess there are many other step results denoted by the X that I just couldn't fully list. Each test case there is a chance that the machine under test can fail and an error will be generated at the node corresponding to the test case (Pressure, flow, leak etc. In this case I chose flow)

I need to find a way to arbitrarily output fail paramaters when a machine has failed. Note that each time a machine fails it outputs a "ProductFailure" status for the last StepResult node. And then from there I need to extract the Lower Limit, Higher Limit and also the Actual Value.

So far I am able to only extract Actual Value by Specifying the node using the script below:

```
Select

f.ResultXML.value('(/TestResults/MethodResult/StepResult[@name="FlowError"]/ActualValue/Number)[1]/@value', 'varchar(max)') As "Actual Value"

From TestResult.ResultData
```

However the code above will only output values when a machine fails for flow. Pressure Error and Leak error for example will not show a value (which I also need)

I thought I could simply change @Name into @Status and ask it to look for "ProductFailure" it would give me the failed step results everytime rather than me specifying FlowError but it instead returns a Null every time.

I am wondering how I can Extract the strings for Actual Value, Higher Limit and Lower Limit without me having to specify the Actual Error Message "FlowError" or any other errors.

Thanks in advance

## Edit:

Adding actual XML from database [MSPTestResult].[MSPTestResult].[ResultData] which I will delete later on due to potential sensitive information.

## Edit:

Question answered, the issue was that my query needed to specify every single node that is unique like StepResult[@name="Product failure"] and then going into Limit[@constraint type = "In Range"] etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are getting an error for `status="productFailure"`, as this all works for me:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml=convert(xml,'<TestResult>
<MethodResult>
 <StepResult />
 <StepResult />
 <StepResult />
 <StepResult name = "FlowError" status = "ProductFailure"> 
  <ActualValue>
    <Number value = "3" />
  </ActualValue>
  <Limit constraint_Type = "In Range" name="FlowError">
    <Low>
      <Number value = "5" />
    </Low>
    <High>
      <Number value = "6" />
    </High>
  </Limit>
  <Error source = "X" code = "Y" mesg = "Failed for X Value was 3 expected 5 to 6" /> 
</StepResult>
</MethodResult>
</TestResult>')
select @xml.query('/TestResult/MethodResult/StepResult[@status="ProductFailure"]')
select @xml.value('(/TestResult/MethodResult/StepResult[@status="ProductFailure"]/ActualValue/Number)[1]/@value', 'varchar(10)') As "Actual Value"
select @xml.value('(/TestResult/MethodResult/StepResult[@status="ProductFailure"]/Limit/Low/Number)[1]/@value', 'varchar(10)') As "Low Value"
select @xml.value('(/TestResult/MethodResult/StepResult[@status="ProductFailure"]/Limit/High/Number)[1]/@value', 'varchar(10)') As "High Value"
```

The results I see are the complete FlowError (identified by the status check), then the three values for Actual, High and Low values.

EDIT: (After the entire actual XML was posted)
The xml is a bit different to the original example, and the `ProductFailure` node does not have a max and min node, nor a `/ActualValue/Number` node.

The following two lines retrieve the values for `ActualValue` and `Less Than`

```
select @xml.value('(/TestResults/MethodResult/StepResult[@status="ProductFailure"]/ActualValue/Flow)[1]/@value', 'varchar(10)') As "Actual Value"
select @xml.value('(/TestResults/MethodResult/StepResult[@status="ProductFailure"]/Limit[@constraintType="LessThan"]/Value/Flow)[1]/@value', 'varchar(10)') As "Less Than"
```

If different types of errors have different types of content, then you will need to either try each possible combination or find some other way to identify them, possibly positional, or possibly by getting all the `@value` attributes and working out min/max/actual from their relative values.

Comment: Using your piece of code isolated, it works perfectly. However I am not sure why it doesn't work when I place it in conjunction with my complete query. Other XML related queries like Error source, code and message work, just querying the actual values and limits don't.
That said, Maybe this "ProductFailure" Status is not unique to this Step Result. This status also appears in Method Result which is a higher level in the structure, but I have already specified to look in Step Result instead.

Comment: I tried to use that code in the original query that outputs the XML and it still doesn't work, but specifying "FlowError" in the name does. Therefore it shouldn't be a database link error. It is most likely my syntax of the data structure.

Comment: Maybe post an example of the complete xml then, even if its long, as the answer I posted works with the example you posted. And by the way, the example you posted is badly formed as node `<Limit constraint Type = "In Range" name = "FlowError">` as the word "constraint" isnt valid there, and the node `<Error source="X" code="Y" mesg="Failed for X; Value was 3, expected [5 to 6]/>` is missing a closing quote, and the closing node `</TestResults>` doesnt match the opening node. Some of these might be issues unless they are just typos when creating the question.

Comment: True, i can post the complete XML but it is too long due to 1.5k character limit and it is best if i email it.

Comment: Don't think emailing is an option as it needs to be public for this site. Need to find another public location for it and post the link.

Comment: Added the actual XML output from the database in my original post. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Thanks, at least I now see the nulls.

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to get it working, works like a charm!

Comment: Great @EugeneKwokKitHo. Remember to accept the answer!